# add new subclasses without editing the existing code - avoid Json annotation

Tags: java, json, inheritance

I have the task of writing an application that can allow adding many different subclasses without editing the existing code (only creating new classes)... I use the startegy pattern for the conversion, but I have a problem with the Json annotation in the superclass (@JsonSubTypes) - it has to go away because it causes when adding a new subclass inheriting from a superclass, I must add its type there. There can be up to a hundred inheriting classes...

superclass:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Subclass1.class, name = "subclass1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Subclass2.class, name = "subclass2"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Subclass3.class, name = "subclass3"),
})
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Superclass implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type; 

    ... 
}
```

subclass:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("subclass1")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Subclass1 extends Superclass {

    private String stingField;

}
```

I tried to solve it using Json Deduction (@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION) but in the case of similar classes it doesn't work... Do you have any simple solution for such a problem?